# Can I set theme per file type in Textmate?

Tags: textmate

Can I set theme per file type in Textmate?
..or at least change font my eyes are killing me when I'm switching between programming and writing latex at the same time! for programming I tend to use a small font with clear letters (Monaco, no anti alias) however when I write latex I need bigger font.